# Copy varying columns to single excel sheet using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write and excel macro that will copy data from an excel file with multiple sheets. Each column will have different lengths and the name of the sheet will not always be known. I want it to start by having the user select the original file and a new one be started, which is where it will be copying to. There are multiple columns and only two of them I am interested in. They are the m/z and the intensity. I also have to know which sheet the value came from. I would prefer it if they sheet name was presented in a column next to the combined m/z's and intensity's. I am new to this and can use all the help available.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?  Which part of this is giving you problems?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Just to let you know, we don't write code FOR YOU... We help you when you get stuck. What I would suggest is to use your macro recorder to start off the process and try and make up a program that does what you're trying to achieve... When you get stuck, post here and we're more than ready and willing to help!!

Answer (score 0):

As above - use the macro recorder and make sure you are using named ranges.... an example upload would also help p[eople help you...